# How to filter DataGridView using a textbox in C# Windows Form

Tags: c#

I found a problem on how to filter the list that I have in the data grid view of my the Windows Form.

Basically, I have a textbox and I want that when I enter value in it, it will filter the Data Grid View.

I do not have any errors, but when I try to write text in the text box, the grid view remains the same and does not filter anything.

The following is my FormLoad (Where it fills the gridview)

```
private void Transactions_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<LogsViewModel> logs = sr.GetTransactions().ToList();
        dgvTransactions.DataSource = sr.GetTransactions().ToList();
    }
```

The following is when I input text in the textbox:

```
private void txtAccountID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dgvTransactions.DataSource;
        bs.Filter = dgvTransactions.Columns[1].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + txtAccountID.Text + "%'";
        dgvTransactions.DataSource = bs.DataSource;
    }
```

Please help! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You need to call the `DataBind()` method in your `txtAccountID_TextChanged()` event.

```
private void txtAccountID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dgvTransactions.DataSource;
        bs.Filter = dgvTransactions.Columns[1].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + txtAccountID.Text + "%'";
        dgvTransactions.DataSource = bs.DataSource;
        dgvTransactions.DataBind();
    }
```

I'm not in a position to test this, but it still might not update until you press the `Enter` key or cause the `TextBox` to lose focus.

Comment: @TestWell 
Thanks for your time, but unfortunately it didn't work because DataBind was not found.

Answer (score -1):

```html
private void txtAccountID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  (dgvTransactions.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Field = '{0}'", textBoxFilter.Text);
}
```

Comment: @Balaji 
I tried that line of code in my method, but it didnt worked.
The error msg was:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Grant Winney.. Why do you suggest me to do pls? Thanks